# Como fazer MaskMoney carregar corretamente valor no input ao entrar na página

Tags: php, maskmoney

Estou tentando sem sucesso fazer o MaskMoney carregar o valor formato ao entrar na página, sei que tem um link aqui mesmo no SO com uma pergunta similar, mas mesmo com o exemplo não estou conseguindo.

O valor no meu BD está gravado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No banco o campo está definido assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu input está assim:

```
<input type="text" id="UpUltimoSalario" name="UpUltimoSalario" value="" class="form-control" >
```

E o que tentei até agora:

```
// MÁSCARA PARA VALORES
$(function() {
  var maxLength = '-0.000.000,00'.length;
  $("#UpUltimoSalario").maskMoney({
     // allowNegative: true,
     decimal: ',',
     thousands: '.',
     affixesStay: false
  })
      .attr('maxlength', maxLength).trigger('mask.maskMoney');
});
```

Ao abrir a minha modal o valor fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no input fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inserindo valor retornado na Modal:

```
// INSERINDO REGISTROS NA MODAL - ALTERAÇÃO
function Alteracao(Historico) {
    $.post("pDetalhesHistoricoProfissional-2-bkp.php", {
            Historico: Historico
        },
        function (data, status) {
            // PARSE json data
            var dados = JSON.parse(data);   
                // CHAVES PARA ALTERAÇÃO
                $("#IdHistorico").val(dados.IdHistorico);   
                $("#IdCandidato").val(dados.IdCandidato);
                // CARREGA VALORES NA MODAL
                $("#UpEmpresa").val(dados.Empresa);
                $("#UpCargo").val(dados.Cargo);
                $("#UpDataEntrada").val(dados.DataEntrada);
                $("#UpDataSaida").val(dados.DataSaida);
                $("#UpUltimoSalario").val(dados.UltimoSalario);
                $("#UpAtividades").val(dados.Atividades);   
            }
    );
    // ABRE MODAL PARA ALTERAÇÃO
    $("#ModalAlteracao").modal("show");
}
```

Comment: Quando puxar o valor do banco, faz 2 replaces: o primeiro tirando todos os pontos, e o segundo substituindo a vírgula por um ponto. Isso no back-end.

Comment: Se o problema é com o MaskMoney, que é em JavaScript, o problema pode e deve ser reduzido a um [mcve] que não dependa do PHP. Você pode apenas citar que o valor que chegou do banco de dados foi X e a partir disso montar o problema apenas com o JS. Todo o trecho PHP da pergunta não tem relação com o problema e só está poluindo sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, talvez queira trabalhar com outra biblioteca.

**UPDATE**
Adicionado exemplo com a biblioteca `MaskMoney`

[exemplo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fjtdcxk/8/)

```js
$(function () {
 console.log('init app');
 $('#UpUltimoSalario').val('3.555,00');
 $('#mask').val('3.555,00');

 $('#btn-modal-maskmoney').click(function () {
  showModel();
 });

 initMaskMoney();
 setMask();

});

function initMaskMoney() {
 $("#UpUltimoSalario").maskMoney({
  showSymbol: true,
  symbol: "R$",
  decimal: ",",
  thousands: ".",
  affixesStay: false
 });
}

function setMask() {
 $('.money').mask('#.##0,00', {
  reverse: true,
  maxlength: false
 });
}

function showModel() {
 let modal = $('#modal-maskmoney');

 modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).find('input:visible:first').focus();
 });

 modal.modal('show');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
         <button type="button" id="btn-modal-maskmoney" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
         Click Me
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
         <label>Mask</label>
         <input type="text" id="mask" class="form-control money" >
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- The modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-maskmoney" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Mask-Money</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" id="UpUltimoSalario" name="UpUltimoSalario" value="" class="form-control money" >
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agradeço a colaboração @Wagner Filho, mas não gostaria de usar outra biblioteca.

Comment: @adventistapr, atualizei a questão.

Comment: Valeu @Wagner Filho, ajudou demais.